# Twitter bootstrap grid -simulate rowspan

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid using twitter bootstrap that we are converting from a table.  Ordinarily we would consider this tabular data and just use a table but we have to (client requirements) be able to reliably print the table and given the bag of hurt printing log tables is, I'm migrating to bootstrap grids.

What I need to be able to simulate is the rowspan that we're currently using in the table.

Note I'm using a custom bootstrap with a grid of 10 cols because of size constraints

JS Fiddle of example http://jsfiddle.net/dstarh/hKjEM/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">Date</div>
        <div class="span2" style="text-align:center;">Total Time</div>
        <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">Time of activity</div>
        <div class="span1" style="text-align:left;">Time of Day</div>
        <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">Distance</div>
        <div class="span4" style="text-align:left;">Description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1" style="height:100%;">01/31/2013</div>
                <div class="span2" style="height:100%;">8 hours/12 miles
                    <hr> <span class="target-calories">
                      TARGET 15 miles
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">1 hour</div>
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:left;">morning</div>
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">3 miles</div>
                <div class="span4" style="text-align:left;">ran 3 miles</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">1 hour</div>
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:left;">noon</div>
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">2 miles</div>
                <div class="span4" style="text-align:left;">walked 2 miles</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1 offset2" style="text-align:right;">2 miles</div>
                <div class="span4" style="text-align:left;">biked 2 miles</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1 offset2" style="text-align:right;">4 miles</div>
                <div class="span4" style="text-align:left;">ran 4 miles</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">4 miles</div>
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:left;">night</div>
                <div class="span1" style="text-align:right;">4 miles</div>
                <div class="span4" style="text-align:left;">ran 4 miles</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I need the first two columns (inside the span3) to be vertically centered next to the rest of the columns/rows ).  The number of rows on the right (in the span 7) is random, anywhere from 1 to likely 10-15 on the high end.

Comment: Your HTML markup was a disaster of missing quotes and incorrectly closed tags. Here's a better starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/WfDUY/

Comment: Yea I realized that, editing and adding my fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you close. You do have to stretch the frame wide enough to allow responsive to do its thing. Note that vertical alignment is a challenge in itself and may require a nested table or JavaScript solution (see below).

http://jsfiddle.net/WfDUY/4/

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.gray {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.grayer {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">I want to be Vertically Aligned in the middle</div>
            <div class="span7 offset3">
...
```

Here's an example with the nested table solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WfDUY/6/